# In Xcode 6 not appear auto suggestion list when press Ctrl + Space

Tags: ios, xcode6

I am facing one weird issues.
- when I press Ctrl + Space, it doesn't show auto suggestion list.
- IBOutlet created into .h file can not be found into Main storyboard, But when I delete these .h & .m files and re-import them then it will show IBOutlets into storyboard.

These issues are only happen with one specific project. Other projects are working fine. 
Please suggest me.

Comment: tried product -> clean?

Comment: Delete Derived Data, clean build folder, restart Xcode, restart Mac.

Comment: Yes. I do that. When I close Xcode and restart Xcode, then it work. But after some times, it happen again.